# How to fix this very simple if statement?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I've been looking on how to make a simple coin flip script using JavaScript, and I've seen videos of people that seem to over-complicate things using 20 different elements or whatever you call them. What I set out to do is create a "magic 8 ball" kind of script but only using simple commands. I have it working so that I have a text box, then next to it is a button when pressed it will execute a function.

#### My problem:

T
Instead of returning a number when using `Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)`, I want to return the words like "yes" "no" "maybe" etc. Additionally, I was wondering what the `()` do in `Math.random()`.
My code is below. The first statement works if nothing is typed in it says "please enter a question" but the rest doesn't.

```js
function checkFunction() {

  if (question.value == '') {

    document.getElementById("fortune").innerHTML = "Please Enter A Question";

} else {

  Math.floor(Math.random(data) * 4);

 if (data == 0) {

      document.getElementById("fortune").innerHTML = "Maybe";

 } else if (data == 1) {

  document.getElementById("fortune").innerHTML = "Try Again";

 } else if (data == 2) {

  document.getElementById("fortune").innerHTML = "Yes";

 } else if (data == 3) {

  document.getElementById("fortune").innerHTML = "No";

 } else {

  return "Invalid";
 }
}
}
```

I don't care if it's long, I just want it to be simple.  I don't want to have to define a bunch of variables and mess around with calling them up because I'm just trying to take it a step at a time.  I'm basically trying to figure out the maximum potential of an if statement before moving on and learning new things.

Comment: Just use an array.

Comment: @xaxxon It clearly asks a question, so no, it doesn't belong there. It belongs here.

Comment: There's no reason to make an object with numeric keys when that already exists - an array, @tewathia.

Comment: Your Math.random generate 0 to 3. so the last `else` ('Invalid') never happening. Drop the last `else` or create 0-4 like my answer If you really need it. Also drop `data` from Math.random() as @CodingYoshi said.

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering what the () do in Math.random().

`Math.random()` is a function and it takes no parameters.  The `()` means it's a function. You are passing `data` to the function but the function will not use it because it is parameterless.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like to have that return:

```
function checkFunction() {

    var arr = ['Maybe','Try Again','Yes','No'],
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); //0 to 4

    document.getElementById('fortune').innerHTML = (question.value=='')? 'Please Enter A Question' : (index<arr.length)? arr[index] : 'Invalid';
}
```

If you like to have the return use this:

```
function checkFunction() {

    var arr = ['Maybe','Try Again','Yes','No'],
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); //0 to 4

    var tmp = (question.value=='')? 'Please Enter A Question' : (index<arr.length)? arr[index] : false;

    if (tmp===false){
        return 'Invalid';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('fortune').innerHTML = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a literal, there's no point setting every element one by one.

Comment: I'd just like to note the OP's statement *"I'm basically trying to figure out the maximum potential of an if statement before moving on and learning new things."*

Comment: Yes but that's at odds with 'simple'. The simple, sane thing here is to not use an if statement @TrojanByAccident

Comment: @pvg True. Even a `switch` would be better :P

Comment: @ICE the convoluted typeof thing seems completely superfluous. Can just generate the random index based on array length.

Comment: @pvg fixed it. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: See that's what I mean by trying to keep it simple.  I used a bunch of if statements when scripting inside a game so I'm familiar with them.  But when you start throwing in the arrays and variables is when I have a hard time figuring out what connects to what and what each one does.  I mean I know I sound stupid when I say this, but I don't want to learn all that stuff yet.  This is basically the same as learning a whole new language.  You don't learn how to structure sentences first, you learn how to say individual words.

Comment: One last thing, to give you an idea on what level I'm at, I don't even understand what the document.getElementById().innerHTML does.  I just read it off the wiki and know that it does what I want it to do.  I mean from my limited time scripting I can kind of understand it but I usually still have to look back on a separate file or the wiki to know what to type because I haven't memorized it.

Comment: @Jones you can easily read my answer if you know `if (condition==true){ t = 1; } else { t = 2; }` is equal to `t = (condition==true)? 1 : 2;` If you want to learn JavaScript I recommend to use something like http://www.w3schools.com/js/ or https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/

Comment: I don't know that though.  All I know is if () {} else {}.  I don't know what the rest is.  It's okay though.  I'm using codeacadamy so I'll just keep working through it and refer to w3schools if I need to relearn things.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Math.floor(Math.random(data) * 4);
```

ignores the parameter `data` because `Math.random`  doesn't take a parameter. The expression statement evaluates to an integer value in range [0, 4). After execution `data` is still undefined (or whatever it was before).

You could use an integer random number generator function such as:

```
function randomInt( low, high) {
   var range = high - low + 1;
   return low + Math.floor( range * Math.random());
}
```

to return an integer in the inclusive range [low, high] when called.